# Sunspot: How does the delta indexing work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, sunspot

I am investigating Sunspot as a possible indexing solution for our project. There is one thing, I don't find any information about though: How are updates to the data handled. If I have "setup" the class I wish to index, how does the solr server get notified about changes to the object?

In addition, consider the following scenario:

I have class Artwork which "has_many" Synonym and I would construct my index this way:

```
Sunspot.setup(Artwork)
  text :synonyms do
    synonyms.map { |s| s.name }
  end
end
```

Given an artwork "Mona Lisa" with the synonyms "La Gioconda" and "Not so big smile". When I now update the last synonym, would solr be notified and would it rebuild the index for "Mona Lisa"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Sunspot::Rails and an ActiveRecord model, there is a lifecycle hook that will automatically update the record's data in Solr whenever the model is saved. However the above looks like you're using pure Sunspot, in which case you'll need to set up your own lifecycle hook, e.g.:

```
after_save { |artwork| Sunspot.index(artwork) }
```

You'll also need your own lifecycle logic for any situation in which updating a dependent model needs to update the parent document in Solr (e.g. updates directly to the Synonym models above).

Comment: Thanks a lot .. exactly what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such automatic notification exist with Solr. As the synonyms are stored in the txt file, you will have to restart solr server and then reindex. The same case with any solr configuration.

Comment: Are you sure of that? I ask because I read this: http://www.vijedi.net/2010/ruby-full-text-search-performance-thinking-sphinx-vs-sunspot-solr/ where it says: "Solr servers can be clustered and since they manage the index, Sunspot can automatically update the indexes when the model objects change. There’s no need to run a cron job to reindex the data or setup delta indexing like with Thinking Sphinx."

Comment: When you change the model, you don't have to reindex manually. I am talking about reindexing when the configuration of the solr itself changes like when you change Analyzers or when you change synonyms etc. Hope its clear

Comment: Yes, I know I have to do a full reindex in those cases. But in my (above) scenario, I do not change the configuration, just the data. So I am wondering if solr will get notified (not only if the model data changes but if the associations' data changes).